# Flutter: How to initialize an empty list for every Object in an Array?

Tags: arrays, list, flutter, default, empty-list

Hi I'm very new to flutter and coding in general therefore my approach on this might not be the cleanest. Anyways:

I'm storing data in an Array and use the Array-Items to build ListTiles. Now I want to add the possibility to write comments to a Tile and store the input-data like author-name, time and the Comment-Text to the Array/Item. 
As there aren't any comments in the beginning, every Item should have an empty List of comments to start with. When I initialize the empty list for a single Item it works and I can add TextData to the list. But because my Array is very large I can't initialize the empty list for every single Item. Therefore I'm searching for a way to set the default for every Item to be an empty list without the List being a const List, as I can't add to the const List.

```
// DataType to store a single comment with further information

class TextData {
  Text({
    this.text,
    this.author,
    this.time,
});
  final String text;
  final String author;
  final time;
}

//All the Data for one ArrayItem including a List of Comments

class Data {
  Data({
    this.data1,
    this.data2,

    this.comments,
  });

  final String data1;
  final String data2;

// List of comments for one ArrayItem

  List<TextData> comments;
}
```

I don't get any error messages I just can't add to the list if it isn't initialized or its initialized as a default.

I appreciate any Help. 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 10):

Why don't you just write that in your Data class:

```
List<TextData> comments = []
```

instead of

```
List<TextData> comments;
```

Comment: I've tried this but it doesn't seem to initialize it, because when I print it it prints null and not [ ]. 
I worked around it by checking if it is null the first time someone adds a comment with:

    `Data[index].comments == null ? Data[index].comments = [] : ...`

But this is only a workaround and I'd still like to know if it is possible to do it in a different way.

Comment: Well in your constructor, add : [] after the this.comments ! So it'll look like this : this.comments: []

Answer (score 0):

Make the comments a @required parameter. This would make your code look like this...

```
// DataType to store a single comment with further information

class TextData {
  Text({
    this.text,
    this.author,
    this.time,
});
  final String text;
  final String author;
  final time;
}

//All the Data for one ArrayItem including a List of Comments

class Data {
  Data({
    this.data1,
    this.data2,

    @required this.comments,
  });

  final String data1;
  final String data2;

// List of comments for one ArrayItem

  List<TextData> comments;
}
```

At least this way you will be prompted to add an empty list when you instantiate a new Data object like so...

```
var data = Data(comments: []);
```

This is what I've done in my Flutter Classes where I want to make sure that there is an empty list so that I don't have to check it before adding anything to that list.